# clear edittext when button is pressed

Tags: java, android, textview, android-edittext, textwatcher

I want my onTextChanged class to read when the user enters a "space", so that i can clear my EditText view.  The problem is that nothing happens when the space bar is pressed.  Does anybody know what im doing wrong?  My program does not crash it just does nothing.

```
 public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                    int count) {
                SS.setText(s);
                if (s.equals("r")) {
                    SS.setText(s);
                    et.setText(" ");
                }
            }

                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                        int after) {
                    et.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));

                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(final Editable s) {
                    // cancel the previous search if any

                    // toasted();
                    if (delayedAction != null) {
                        handler.removeCallbacks(delayedAction);
                    }
                    // toasted();

                    // define a new search
                    delayedAction = new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            // start your search
                            // toasted();

                            // if (s.toString().equals(current)) {
                            // // toasted(); <== Here is where it needs to work
                            // // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            // }

                            et.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#C0C0C0"));
                            toasted();
                            tv.setText(et.getText().toString());
                            tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#66CC66"));
                            et.setText("");
                        }

                    };
```

Comment: Try this: `et.setText(""); //no space`. I'm not sure but I think you are making an infinite loop.

Comment: An what is the value of `SS`?

Comment: i made a new textview to print out the value of s.  and the name of the textview is SS

Comment: I was able to get SS to print, SS does get the value of s now, i'll repost edited code, but i still have the problem of getting my program to read a key and start another action

Answer (score 1):

it should be `s.equals(" ")` instead of `s.equals(' ')`

Comment: ive tried that and got the same result, but ill change it back to that .

Comment: It worked for me. May be log and see what "s" is coming as, more than one space?

Comment: From what i've tested, s, does not have a value.  I was convinced that s was the users input.  I will post the full segment of code

Answer (score 0):

You can try it.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\s");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
boolean found = matcher.find();
```